# Nuget pack without OS-specific TFMs

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package

I had a need for my output DLL files to be located in a Nuget package without taking into account OS-specific TFMs.

My project has target framework **<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>**

If the project is configured to build a package, the output file will be located in **$(BuildOutputTargetFolder)\TargetFramework** for this example it will be **lib\net6.0-windows** but i need in **lib\net6.0**

I tried disabling automatic adding **<IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>** but then all output files must be added manually

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net6.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

this would work if it weren't for the problem with adding localization files.

```
<None Include="$(OutputPath)be\$(AssemblyName).resources.dll*" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net6.0\be" />
```

But localization files are added if they have already been created. those. during the first assembly they are not added, but when reassembling they are added.

Maybe there is a solution to my problem?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. As I understand it, you want a DLL compiled for `net8.0-windows` to be located in `lib/net8.0` inside the NuGet package?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.